# ntfs_pread failed - unable to mount

Tags: hard-drive, mount, ntfs

My WD Passport external driver had been working well for several months.
Recently I've been having random restarts in my laptop which has been since fixed. But I am not sure if that's what caused my hard disk to fail or if its something else but I am not able to mount it at all! I keep getting this message:

> Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/steve/My Passport: Command-line
>   `mount -t "ntfs" -o
>   "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1001,gid=1001,dmask=0077,fmask=0177"
>   "/dev/sdc1" "/media/steve/My Passport"' exited with non-zero exit
>   status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
>   Failed to read vcn 0x1: Input/output error Failed to mount
>   '/dev/sdc1': Input/output error NTFS is either inconsistent, or there
>   is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the
>   first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice.
>   The usage of the /f parameter is very important! If the device is a
>   SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device
>   under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1).
>   Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.

On Windows its not even shown in My Computer. When I go to disk management after about 30 mins or so I see the drive showing up but still it comes as RAW and I am not able to open it in Explorer. I tried `chkdsk /f` for an hour or so but it was very slow and it said few times "removing attribute... " and sometimes "unreadable entry" (or something). Later I cancelled it.

I heard `TestDisk` can help but I am not sure how to use it to fix the issue. I thought of copying the files by using the utility in TestDisk but it showed only one folder in the disk and even that was empty.

I have very important backup data in this disk... is there any way to retrieve the data?

THanks!

Comment: I believe TestDisk is more for finding lost partitions due to partition table problems. I would use ntfsclone with the rescue option to attempt a recovery.

Comment: Oh! wow never heard of ntfsclone. Will try that out today. Thanks @ssnobody

Comment: I tried `ntfsclone` but after few seconds it started giving these messages - `ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read of MFT, mft=20031 count=1 br=-1: Input/output error`.

It started out at `mft=19300` or something.. It keeps going on. On one occasion I saw it say 2.5% complete but then it started giving these messages again.

Is this okay? Do I let it continue?

Comment: I would let it keep going and get as far as it can. You might also try a `ddrescue` if it's more likely the hardware is faulty and software level OS corruption.